# GetTickCount() аналоги?

Tags: linux, c, таймер

```
static int timer = 0;
if ( GetTickCount() - timer > 30000 ) //1 раз в 30 секунд
{
  //code
  timer = GetTickCount();
}
```

Привет друзья, подскажите как реализовать аналог для си линукс? именно такой тип

Comment: добавьте метку к вопросу, соответствующую языку программирования

Comment: Смотрите [clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, ...)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) (ну, и секунды с наносекундами вам надо будет перевести в миллисекунды)

Answer (score 0):

Как @avp уже [сказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222524/gettickcount-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8#comment2139554_1222524), можно использовать [clock_gettime(...)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##dZDLTsMwEEX3@YpRI5ADpYSHQOK1IEIIFZRN2CFZxXaK1cSO4jEb1G8PY7c8isos7Ks7R9fjEQeimZn5MKTaiMZLBVcOpTY4ebtJfjzUrdp0AmWDlXiiT445wr3CSotFYb1BlsFHAlTK@HYtU11LVUPxWBZTfluWVfXwdBc7oV6tRR7e4VrC9TYqVY1T//Hna8RIXUe5vIyXw94LhAC6TgkIx6ojGisWfK4w9NjvuDHsBixbcb1C3xtgX//MGIv67JR04Cb4zh3hsAdHeZ7DPmwBTCQOI0FF2cskIQjamTbf2@p6smo2eu4qGuUCdjy07sWMxn@WuzlaTmHD8Ak)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t GetTickCount() {
    enum {
    #ifdef CLOCK_BOOTTIME
        boot_time_id = CLOCK_BOOTTIME
    #else
        boot_time_id = 7
    #endif
    };
    struct timespec spec;
    clock_gettime(boot_time_id, &spec);
    return (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)spec.tv_sec) * 1000 + ((uint64_t)spec.tv_nsec) / 1000000);
}

int main() {
    printf("UpTime: %u ms\n", GetTickCount());
    return 0;
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
UpTime: 489962023 ms
```